# Chain up to 'Gtk.Box.new' not supported

Tags: oop, gtk, vala

I'm new to Vala and so far I think it's pretty cool but I'm having trouble understanding inheritance. I read [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/ValaForJavaProgrammers#Inheritance) that I should use `base()` to call the parents constructor. Alright, cool, seems understandable but It din't work for me. I kept getting the error on the title. Here is my snippet to show:

```
public class MyBox : Gtk.Box {
    public MyBox(Gtk.Orientation orientation, int spacing) {
        // I have to this
        this.set_orientation(orientation);
        this.set_spacing(spacing);
        // I want to do this:
        base(orientation, spacing);
        //workaround is this:
        Object(orientation: orientation, spacing: spacing);
    }
}
```

Please help me understand why Object(....) works but not base(...)

Shouldn't it be the same thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to implementation of the C code. When Vala generates a constructor, it generates two C functions a `_new` function that allocates memory and calls the `_construct` and a `_construct` function that initialises the object. When you case the base constructor using `base()`, it needs a matching `_construct` function to call. Not all the classes written in C have this; in the VAPI file, you will find `has_construct_function = false` for some constructors. If this is the case, no chain-up can be done. The base `GObject` can set properties from arguments, so this becomes the only way to set defaults in the base class.

Comment: That was a perfect explanation. So whenever I get a chain up error, this would be **only** way to resolve it?

Comment: Yes. In the case of those constructors, the parameters are the same as passing them by name to the `Object` constructor, so it's not lacking any functionality.