# error: field ‘parent_instance’ has incomplete type GtkLabel parent_instance;

Tags: gtk, vala, gtk4

Problem:

I want to make a Gtk.Label child but it seems I cannot make a child of that type. I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872925/chain-up-to-gtk-box-new-not-supported?noredirect=1&lq=1) to find a possible fix, but I cannot get my head around it. What should I do in my case to fix that problem. I basically only want a button with an extra property. Thanks you!

Error:

```
error: field ‘parent_instance’ has incomplete type
   64 |         GtkLabel parent_instance;

error: unknown type name ‘GtkLabelClass’
   69 |         GtkLabelClass parent_class;
```

Snippet:

```
namespace Redacted {
    public class StyleLabel : Gtk.Widget {
        public StyleLabel(Redacted.Preferences.Styles style) {
            Object (label: style.ToString ());
            this.style = style;
        }

        public Redacted.Preferences.Styles style { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of widgets in GTK4 have been marked as "final", which means you can't actually derive a subclass from them anymore. You can also see this in the original [`GtkLabel` documentation](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.Label.html), where it mentions "final class Gtk.Label".

GTK4 prefers composition over inheritance (for several reasons) so when you're writing a UI and you write a custom widget, the way to do this in GTK 4 is to put a `Gtk.Label` *inside* your widget (using [`Gtk.Widget.set_parent()`](https://valadoc.org/gtk4/Gtk.Widget.set_parent.html)). You can find some more explanation and an example at [this topic](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/gtk4-preference-of-composition-over-inheritence/3855) in the GNOME discourse forum.

(as a side note: technically, you could also write your own version of Gtk.Label, but that would be a lot of work for very little gain)